# Is there something changed on express, router, consign or I just don't know what I'm doing so wrong?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, controller, backend

I have installed my dependencies, I've set up my app, but now I'm trying to set a route using consign and I can't find my folder through the middleware using consign.

```
1 const app = require('express')();
2 const consign = require('consign');
3 const routes = require('./routes');
4
5 require('./database');
6
7 consign()
8   .then('./src/config/middlewares.js')
9   .then('./src/routes.js')
10   .into(app)
11
12 app.listen(3000,async () => {
13   console.log('Server running on port 3000...');
14 });
15
```

It calls my app structure well

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in F:\nodejs\backendtest
+ .\src\config\middlewares.js
Server running on port 3000...
```

Here is my package.json:

```
1 {
2   "name": "backendtest",
3   "version": "1.0.0",
4   "main": "index.js",
5   "license": "MIT",
6  "scripts": {
7     "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
8   },
9   "dependencies": {
10     "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
11     "consign": "^0.1.6",
12     "cors": "^2.8.5",
13     "express": "^4.17.1",
14     "mysql2": "^2.3.0",
15     "sequelize": "^6.6.5"
16   },
17   "devDependencies": {
18     "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
19    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
20   }
21 }
22
```

I'm trying to create a user controller simple like this:

```
1 module.exports = app => {
2   const store = (req, res) => {
3     res.send('user stored');
4   }
5
6  return { create, }
7 }
8
```

And my middleware is it:

```
1 const express = require('express');
2 const cors = require('cors');
3
4 module.exports = app => {
5   app.use(express.json());
6   app.use(cors());
}7 
8
```

My rutes.js should be like this:

```
1 module.exports = app => {
2  app.route('/users')
3    .post(app.src.controllers.UserController.store)
4 }
5
```

But when I execute the backend I get this error:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in F:\nodejs\backendtest
+ .\src\config\middlewares.js
+ .\src\routes.js
F:\nodejs\backendtest\src\routes.js:3
    .post(app.src.controllers.UserControler.store)
                              ^
```

Is someone seeing something I don't or am I just using some lib in the wrong way?

Comment: check the path of your consign, You are accessing the route from the same folder as an app but in consignyou are using /src

Comment: Thank you, but changin it did't change the error message

Comment: I had to change all the structure of my folders inside the app to get it working

Comment: You could post your answer. It will good for those who are looking for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to instead of using that folder structure, recreated it as it:

I have now index.js into the root, an api folder to store my user.js (not UserController anymore just to make it simpler), a config folder whre inside of it I have my middlewares.js the same way as before:

```
1 const express = require('express');
2 const cors = require('cors');
3
4 module.exports = app => {
5   app.use(express.json());
6   app.use(cors());
7 }
8
```

My routes.js is now inside my config folder and has the same lines as before:

```
1 module.exports = app => {
2   app.route('/users')
3     .post(app.api.user.save)
4 }
5
```

And I have an index into the root:

```
1 const app = require('express')();
2 const consign = require('consign');
3
4 consign()
5   .then('./config/middlewares.js')
6   .then('./api')
7   .then('./config/routes.js')
8   .into(app);
9
10 app.listen(3000, () => {
11   console.log('running backend on port 3000');
12 });
13
```

And now no error message anymore:

```
$ nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in F:\nodejs\tchuhim
+ .\config\middlewares.js
+ .\api\user.js
+ .\config\routes.js
running backend on port 3000
```